# How should I read it to understand?

Tags: c++, while-loop, readfile

How exactly I should read it? I know what this is doing but how?
Why is the iteration in braces of while loop not in iteration section of loop{}

```
const int array_size = 150;
string file_text_array[array_size];

if (read_file.is_open()) {
    int count = 0;
    while (count < array_size && read_file >> file_text_array[count]) {
        count++;
    }
    read_file.close();
}
```

I know that this is writing strings from file into array. But why `read_file >> file_text_array[count]` is in `while` bracket.

Comment: if the read failed at any point (like reaching the end of the file or some other problem) the loop would end instead of trying to read data that is not there.

Comment: you need to find the declarations of `read_file` to know for sure what is going on. Most probably it is an `ifstream`

Comment: then you read documentation https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool

Comment: `while (stream >> variable) { ... }` is a common C++ idiom for reading a sequence of values from a stream.

Answer (score 2):

This basic pattern is reading from an input stream into a variable until the input fails.

```
while (istream >> var) { ... }
```

Combining this with a check on `count` and incrementing `count` on each iteration is reading into sequential array positions, and ensures we don't run off the end of the array.

Because `count` is scoped outside the while loop, we can know how many values were read.